# How to share a single file in Hyper-V without changes to the network configuration?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I wish to "send" a "single file" on Hyper-V from host to guest, with Windows 8 both at host and guest machines.

I can not allowed to do any configuration or changes of network properties on the host at all.

I just need only to send a single file from the host to the guest. Not to share resources, not share folders, nor share network devices, internet, disks, etc.

Comment: Place file on optical disk, burn optical disk, attach optical disk to virtual machine.

Comment: As currently configured, are both the host and guest connected to the same network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable RDP on the guest, Open `mstsc.exe` making sure you `share` a local drive.

In mstsc.exe `Show Options` - `Local Resources` tab, `More...` button, then check the local drive which has the file you want to send.

After connecting to the guest open Explorer and type `\\tsclient\x` into the address bar, where `x` is the local drive letter on the host that you shared.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like CDBurnerXP to create an ISO containing your files. Then you mount this file to your VirtualMachine as CDROM-Drive.